# Buildozer compilation with firebase-admin and google-cloud-firestore: "No module named google.auth"

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I'm trying to use Firestore in Kivy app and compile with Buildozer.
The app works perfectly on Windows.
In addition to kivy import, I imported:
pip install firebase-admin
pip install google-cloud-firestore

In the VM of kivy, I put:

```
requirements = kivy, firebase-admin, google-cloud-firestore
```

The build is done without any errors, but the app closes immediately after loading.

Using logcat appears:

```
"ImportError: No module named google.auth"
```

I have already tried to include google-auth in requirements but also did not work.

What could be happening?